# Is there a faster way to query 2 months Data 12 months apart?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have around 500k records per month.  I am writing a report that needs to select 2 months worth of data. A user selected month, and the data from the 12 months prior.

Because of some of my other selection criteria, and the way this data is stored, I find I must run the same query 4 times to get my complete resultset.  This means I need the code to run in an optimal way - nobody likes to sit waiting while the screen says "loading" ;-)

Here is the SQL I am running:

```
Declare @ReportDate DateTime
SET @ReportDate = dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, sysdatetime()), 0))


CREATE TABLE #DailyVolumes
(contract_name   VARCHAR(50),
Volume          INT,
date_registered DATETIME
);

INSERT into #DailyVolumes(contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
SELECT 
   CONCAT('L1-',a.contract_code) AS contract_name
   ,count(distinct(CONCAT(rtrim(p.lis_xxxx_id), '-', rtrim(r.lis_req_id)))) AS Volume
   ,a.date_registered
-- Create Temp Table to contain daily data
FROM accession a
   Left  join xxxx P on a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
   Left  join requester R on a.requester_id = r.requester_id
where 
(([date_registered] >= @ReportDate and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,1,@ReportDate))
OR ([date_registered] >= dateadd(month,-12,@ReportDate) and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,-11,@ReportDate)))
-- Limit results to L1
   AND a.lis_code = 'L'
-- Limit results to Visitype NOT I or E
   AND visit_type NOT IN('I', 'E')
GROUP BY 
   CONCAT('L1-',a.contract_code)
   ,a.date_registered

INSERT into #DailyVolumes(contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
SELECT 
   CONCAT('L1-',a.contract_code) AS contract_name
   ,count(distinct rtrim(r.lis_req_id)) AS Volume
   ,a.date_registered
-- Create Temp Table to contain daily data
FROM accession a
   Left  join xxxx P on a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
   Left  join requester R on a.requester_id = r.requester_id
where 
(([date_registered] >= @ReportDate and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,1,@ReportDate))
OR ([date_registered] >= dateadd(month,-12,@ReportDate) and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,-11,@ReportDate)))
-- Limit results to L1
   AND a.lis_code = 'L'
-- Limit results to Visitype = I or E
   AND visit_type IN('I', 'E')
GROUP BY 
   CONCAT('L1-',a.contract_code)
   ,a.date_registered

INSERT into #DailyVolumes(contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
SELECT
   CONCAT('L2-',a.contract_code) AS contract_code
   ,count(distinct(CONCAT(rtrim(p.lis_xxxx_id), '-', rtrim(r.lis_req_id)))) AS Volume
   ,a.date_registered
FROM accession a
   Left  join xxxx P on a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
   Left  join requester R on a.requester_id = r.requester_id
where 
(([date_registered] >= @ReportDate and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,1,@ReportDate))
OR ([date_registered] >= dateadd(month,-12,@ReportDate) and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,-11,@ReportDate)))
-- Limit results to L2
   AND a.lis_code = 'S'
-- Limit results to Visitype NOT I or E
   AND visit_type NOT IN('I', 'E')
GROUP BY 
   CONCAT('L2-',a.contract_code)
   ,a.date_registered

INSERT into #DailyVolumes(contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
SELECT
   CONCAT('L2-',a.contract_code) AS contract_code
   ,count(distinct rtrim(r.lis_req_id)) AS Volume
   ,a.date_registered
FROM accession a
   Left  join xxxx P on a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
   Left  join requester R on a.requester_id = r.requester_id
where 
(([date_registered] >= @ReportDate and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,1,@ReportDate))
OR ([date_registered] >= dateadd(month,-12,@ReportDate) and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,-11,@ReportDate)))
-- Limit results to L2
   AND a.lis_code = 'S'
-- Limit results to Visitype = I or E
   AND visit_type IN('I', 'E')
GROUP BY 
   CONCAT('L2-',a.contract_code)
   ,a.date_registered



-- SUM Daily Data into Monthly Slices
Select
   sum(Volume) AS Volume
   ,contract_name
   ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0) AS MonthRegistered
FROM #DailyVolumes
group by 
   contract_name
   ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0)
ORDER BY MonthRegistered DESC
-- Clear Temp Table
DROP TABLE #DailyVolumes
```

This resultset takes approximately 25seconds to return in SSMS.

I DID try running my query 8 times instead of 4 times - once for each of the date clauses above and got the time to return the resultset down to around 6seconds - which is a pretty OK result but seems counter intuitive to me...
EDIT: - The server must have cached the results.  After I left it alone for an hour - I got sort of the result I was expecting - it took around 48 seconds to run.  SO splitting the OR clause and running each of the 4 queries a second time = no net gain.

I would like to know if there could be a more efficient SQL that returns the resultset more quickly.  I believe giving the server an OR satement like this is introducing significant overhead, but I'm not sure of a better way to run this in a single select.

EDIT: date_registered IS INDEXED

Comment: is there an index on date_registered?

Comment: Can you post the full query and the table structure? Don't forget indexes. It would also be extremely helpful to see the execution plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Unfortunately I am SHOWPLAN permission denied...

Comment: The screenshot just shows the name of the indexes. not the columns they cover

Comment: can you add indexes if they are required to speed your query?

Comment: would really like to know why you need to query this 4 times (or 8). Do you use CTEs in your existing query? Please post the entire "4 times query".

Comment: I have now checked - there is definitely an index on date_registered.  Do I need to post details about what the Create Index statement says?

Comment: I have 2 separate locations - each of which has 2 separate types of "visits" I need to count the different types visits using a different algorithm.  1 kind is simply a count distinct.  The other kind has to concat 2 fields together before running a count distinct.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I have now added the full "4 times query" SQL - I do not currently use a CTE in any way.  I probably should, but haven't gone through the work of figuring out how to apply one.  I have very limited exposure to CTEs - and am not all that confident with them yet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my eyes need testing, but I don't actually see why you do 4 queries. However on the assumption my eyes do deceive me, you can use a `common table expression` like this:

```
DECLARE @ReportDate datetime
SET @ReportDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0))

CREATE TABLE #DailyVolumes (
      contract_name varchar(50)
    , Volume int
    , date_registered datetime
);

WITH myCTE as (
      SELECT visit_type, a.lis_code, a.contract_code, a.date_registered, p.lis_xxxx_id, r.lis_req_id
      FROM accession a
      LEFT JOIN xxxx p ON a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
      LEFT JOIN requester r ON a.requester_id = r.requester_id
      WHERE (([date_registered] >= @ReportDate
      AND [date_registered] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @ReportDate))
      OR ([date_registered] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @ReportDate)
      AND [date_registered] < DATEADD(MONTH, -11, @ReportDate)))
      )

INSERT INTO #DailyVolumes (contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
      SELECT
            CONCAT('L1-', a.contract_code)                                           AS contract_name
          , COUNT(DISTINCT (CONCAT(RTRIM(p.lis_xxxx_id), '-', RTRIM(r.lis_req_id)))) AS volume
          , a.date_registered
      -- Create Temp Table to contain daily data
      FROM myCTE a
      -- Limit results to L1
      WHERE a.lis_code = 'L'
      -- Limit results to Visitype NOT I or E
      AND visit_type NOT IN ('I', 'E')
      GROUP BY
            CONCAT('L1-', a.contract_code)
          , a.date_registered

INSERT INTO #DailyVolumes (contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
      SELECT
            CONCAT('L1-', a.contract_code)      AS contract_name
          , COUNT(DISTINCT RTRIM(r.lis_req_id)) AS volume
          , a.date_registered
      -- Create Temp Table to contain daily data
      FROM myCTE a
      WHERE a.lis_code = 'L'
      -- Limit results to Visitype = I or E
      AND visit_type IN ('I', 'E')
      GROUP BY
            CONCAT('L1-', a.contract_code)
          , a.date_registered

INSERT INTO #DailyVolumes (contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
      SELECT
            CONCAT('L2-', a.contract_code)                                           AS contract_code
          , COUNT(DISTINCT (CONCAT(RTRIM(p.lis_xxxx_id), '-', RTRIM(r.lis_req_id)))) AS volume
          , a.date_registered
      FROM myCTE a
      WHERE a.lis_code = 'S'
      -- Limit results to Visitype NOT I or E
      AND visit_type NOT IN ('I', 'E')
      GROUP BY
            CONCAT('L2-', a.contract_code)
          , a.date_registered

INSERT INTO #DailyVolumes (contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
      SELECT
            CONCAT('L2-', a.contract_code)      AS contract_code
          , COUNT(DISTINCT RTRIM(r.lis_req_id)) AS volume
          , a.date_registered
      FROM myCTE a
      WHERE a.lis_code = 'S'
      -- Limit results to Visitype = I or E
      AND visit_type IN ('I', 'E')
      GROUP BY
            CONCAT('L2-', a.contract_code)
          , a.date_registered


-- SUM Daily Data into Monthly Slices
SELECT
      SUM(Volume)                                            AS volume
    , contract_name
    , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0) AS monthregistered
FROM #DailyVolumes
GROUP BY
      contract_name
    , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0)
ORDER BY
      monthregistered DESC
-- Clear Temp Table
DROP TABLE #DailyVolumes
```

Comment: The requirement to run 4 times comes from this:

Comment: - there are 2 locations identified in field a.lis_code

Comment: - each location has one of it's several contracts with the same code as the other location on field a.contract_code.

Comment: - I need to SUM all the contract_codes independently.  So therefore I have to use a combination of Contract_Code  & LIS_CODE to identify them seperately

Comment: This requirement gives a need to run 2 times.  The need to run the OTHER 2 times comes from:

Comment: - Each location has 2 different type of visits - identified by the field visit_type Where selecting for I OR E is one condition, and selecting for NOT I OR E is the other condition.  The different type have a different count distinct algorithm in the 2nd line of the Select

Comment: THANK YOU for providing the myCTE example,  once I changed all my separate INSERT statements to be one statement using union to join them all together in a single INSERT action it worked well.            Sadly - it did not seem to give any performance improvement, ran for just 2 seconds longer.  :(  It DID help me improve my understanding of CTE quite lot however, so the effort on your part is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears if `a.list_code = 'L'` then you want the text 'L1-', otherwise if `a.list_code = 'S'` then you want the text 'L2-'. To do this I used a case statement.

As was written you want `where visit_type IN ('I', 'E')` and `where visit_type not in ('I', 'E')` for the two `a.list_code IN ('L', 'S')`.  Since both go into the same temp table, I've removed multiple queries for filters `('I', 'E')`.  So there is now just 1 query with filter `WHERE a.lis_code IN ('L', 'S')`. I hope that is correct... there is no test data for any of this so I can't verify.

ltrims and rtrims always slow down queries... see if you can remove them.

Here is my attempt:

```
Declare @ReportDate DateTime
SET @ReportDate = dateadd(month,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, sysdatetime()), 0))    

CREATE TABLE #DailyVolumes
(contract_name   VARCHAR(50),
Volume          INT,
date_registered DATETIME
);

INSERT into #DailyVolumes(contract_name, Volume, date_registered)
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN a.lis_code = 'L'
         THEN 'L1-'
         ELSE 'L2-'
   END + a.contract_code AS contract_name
   ,count(distinct(CONCAT(rtrim(p.lis_xxxx_id), '-', rtrim(r.lis_req_id)))) AS Volume
   ,a.date_registered
-- Create Temp Table to contain daily data
FROM accession a
   Left  join xxxx P on a.xxxx_id = p.xxxx_id
   Left  join requester R on a.requester_id = r.requester_id
where 
( ([date_registered] >= @ReportDate and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,1,@ReportDate))
 OR ([date_registered] >= dateadd(month,-12,@ReportDate) and [date_registered] < dateadd(month,-11,@ReportDate))
)
 AND a.lis_code IN ('L', 'S')

GROUP BY 
   CASE WHEN a.lis_code = 'L'
         THEN 'L1-'
         ELSE 'L2-'
   END + a.contract_code
   ,a.date_registered    


-- SUM Daily Data into Monthly Slices
Select
   sum(Volume) AS Volume
   ,contract_name
   ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0) AS MonthRegistered
FROM #DailyVolumes
group by 
   contract_name
   ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date_registered), 0)
ORDER BY MonthRegistered DESC
-- Clear Temp Table
DROP TABLE #DailyVolumes
```